# Probability and distributions

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be the signal emitted by a certain transmitter such that $X$ takes on the values $\pm1$ with equal probability. Suppose the signal is received with some random error, $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Let $Y = X + Z$ be the signal captured by the signal receiver. Assume $Z$ and $X$ are independent.
(a) Derive mathematical expressions for $P (X = 1, Y ≤ y)$ and $P (X = −1, Y ≤ y)$.
(b) Derive a mathematical expression for the marginal probability density function of $Y$.

I'm not sure how to approach and compute this problem. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint on (a):

$P\left(X=1,Y\leq y\right)=P\left(X=1,Z\leq y-1\right)=\dots$ ($X$
and $Z$ are independent)